# *Tangent* at a Point and *Parallel* at a Point

Tags: geometry, derivatives, tangent-line

If we say that a curve is *tangent* to a function at a point, is that equivalent to saying that the curve is *parallel* to said function at said point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the difference is that a parallel curve doesn't necessarily intersect the function at said point but a tangent curve does.

For example: the parabola $f(x)=x^2$ and the line $g(x)=0$ are tangent at $x=0$, but $f(x)$ is parallel to the line $h(x)=-1$ at $x=0$.